# Java Error: illegal start of expression

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm basically refining, completing and trying to compile a test code from a reference book for java beginners. The objective is to create a guessing game wherein the target is located in 3 continuous cells (I'm holding the locations in an array) and the user guesses the cell no. to destroy the target cell by cell.

I checked out half a dozen posts here on the same error, but I couldn't figure out what was going wrong.

This is my error:

```
test.java:5: error: illegal start of expression
 public int[] locations={1,2,3};
 ^
1 error
```

and my code is:

```
public class test{

        public static void main(String[] args){

            test dot=new test();
            public int[] locations={1,2,3};

            dot.setLocationCells(locations);

            String userGuess="2";
            String result = dot.checkYourself(userGuess);
            String testResult="failed";

            if(result.equals("hit")){
                testResult="passed";
            }


          System.out.println(testResult);
        }

public String checkYourself(String stringGuess){
        int guess=Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
        String result="miss";
        int numOfHits=0;

        for(int cell:locations){
            if(guess==cell){
                result="hit";
                numOfHits++;
                break;
                }
            }

        if(numOfHits==locations.length){
            result="kill";
            }

       System.out.println(result);
       return result;
    }


public void setLocationCells( int[] locations){
        int[] locns;
        locns=locations;
        }

}
```

Comment: sometimes there is a problem with the annotation e.g. @Import{xxx,xxx,} there is a extra , before the closing bracket

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Methods can only declare local variables. That is why the compiler reports an error when you try to declare it as public.

In the case of local variables you can not use any kind of accessor (public, protected or private).

You should also know what the static keyword means. In method `checkYourself`, you use the Integer array `locations`.

The static keyword distinct the elements that are accessible with object creation. Therefore they are not part of the object itself.

```
public class Test { //Capitalized name for classes are used in Java
   private final init[] locations; //key final mean that, is must be assigned before object is constructed and can not be changed later. 

   public Test(int[] locations) {
      this.locations = locations;//To access to class member, when method argument has the same name use `this` key word. 
   }

   public boolean checkYourSelf(int value) { //This method is accessed only from a object.
      for(int location : locations) {
         if(location == value) {
            return true; //When you use key word return insied of loop you exit from it. In this case you exit also from whole method.
         }
      }
      return false; //Method should be simple and perform one task. So you can get more flexibility. 
   }
   public static int[] locations = {1,2,3};//This is static array that is not part of object, but can be used in it. 

   public static void main(String[] args) { //This is declaration of public method that is not part of create object. It can be accessed from every place.
      Test test = new Test(Test.locations); //We declare variable test, and create new instance (object) of class Test.  
      String result;
      if(test.checkYourSelf(2)) {//We moved outside the string
        result = "Hurray";        
      } else {
        result = "Try again"
      }
      System.out.println(result); //We have only one place where write is done. Easy to change in future.
   } 
}
```

Comment: My compiler isn't throwing up an error( I simply declared public static int[] locations outside main). Are you sure methods can declare only local variables?

Comment: Yes. When you move the declaration outside main then is no longer in scope of method but in scope of class. And then you can declare it public.

Comment: @AnujaPL, I've re-wrote the class you have designed with some explanations that might be helpful in future.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `public` keyword from `int[] locations={1,2,3};`. An access modifier isn't allowed inside a method, as its accessbility is defined by its method scope.

If your goal is to use this reference in many a method, you might want to move the declaration outside the method.

Answer (score 2):

Declare

```
public static int[] locations={1,2,3};
```

outside of the main method.

Comment: that worked. Can you tell me why I need to do that? Won't the public keyword itself ensure that all my classes and methods inside and outside main can access it?

Comment: You can't use public within a method. If you want other methods/classes to be able to access `locations`, it needs to be declared as public in your class.

Comment: You should not use public static allocation for data flow concepts. It solve the case but is kind of create a design problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int [] locations={1,2,3};

public static test dot=new test();
```

Declare the above variables above the main method and the code compiles fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```