# How to print all invoiceIds and loop them using ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a report to print details. I need to print all the `invoiceIds` in the same document and loop through them, but I cannot find a way to do it. How do I need to print all the invoices?

Main report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="esr-design-40" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" >
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridHeight" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridWidth" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.SnapToGrid" value="false"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.Grid" value="false"/>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="16"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<scriptlet name="esrgenerator" class="dk.comtalk.billing.server.util.ESRGenerator"/>
<parameter name="printAmount" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="customerId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityProvince" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityPostalCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerProvince" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerPostalCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityLogo" class="java.io.File"/>
<parameter name="countryCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="balance" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="carriedBalance" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDueDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="totalWithTax" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="newStatusId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\Ravi Workspace\\Openbrm\\open-brm-openbrm-2.0\\resources\\designs\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select count(*) from payment_invoice p where p.invoice_id=$P{invoiceId};]]>
</queryString>
<field name="payment_count" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<group name="invoice_total">
    <groupFooter>
        <band/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<title>
    <band height="430">
        <image>
            <reportElement x="8" y="0" width="185" height="48" />
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityLogo}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="57" y="120" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerName}]]> </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="57" y="148" width="294" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerPostalCode}+ " " + $P{customerCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="57" y="162" width="211" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{countryCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="57" y="134" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="384" y="103" width="200" height="28" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[1. opomena za neizmireni racun]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="405" y="173" width="179" height="14" />
            <text><![CDATA[Wangen b. Brüttisellen, 13.12.2015]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="36" y="201" width="328" height="19" />
            <text><![CDATA[Postovani gospodine/postovana gospodjo,]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="36" y="220" width="544" height="35" />
            <text><![CDATA[Dozvolite da Vas podsetimo da je, po podacima naseg knjigovodstva od danasnjeg dana, sledeci telefonski racun jos otvoren:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="35" y="317" width="549" height="34" />
            <text><![CDATA[Ukoliko je Vasa uplata za ovde navedeni racun u medjuvremenu vec izvrsena, nemojte uzimati ovu opomenu u obzir. Ukoliko jos nije, molimo Vas da izvrsite uplatu izvrsite odmah.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="35" y="351" width="557" height="69" />
            <text><![CDATA[Imajte u vidu da se kod opomena, uz regularni racun, placa administrativna taksa za obradu u visini od Fr. 20.00. Ev.deaktivacija servisa se, takodje, naplacuje, dodatnih Fr. 20.00. Molimo Vas stoga za postovanje nasih rokova uplate.

  Najlepse hvala.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="36" y="268" width="559" height="60" />
            <subreportParameter name="invoiceId">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoiceId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "ageing-esr-40-srpski-subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="117">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="36" y="101" width="576" height="16" />
            <text><![CDATA[Symphonica AG | Hegnaustrasse 17 | 8602 Wangen b. Brüttisellen | Telefon 0840 988 988 | Fax 043 536 05 43]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="35" y="8" width="243" height="26" />
            <text><![CDATA[S postovanjem,
     BALKATEL | Symphonica A.D.]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<summary>
    <band height="294">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="5" y="56" width="123" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="5" y="68" width="153" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="5" y="81" width="226" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityPostalCode}+ " " + $P{entityCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="5" y="26" width="100" height="15" />
            <text><![CDATA[6301 Zug]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="179" y="26" width="100" height="15" />
            <text><![CDATA[6301 Zug]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="179" y="56" width="123" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="179" y="68" width="149" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="179" y="81" width="226" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityPostalCode}+ " " + $P{entityCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="97" y="110" width="100" height="14" />
            <text><![CDATA[01-2653-5]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="272" y="110" width="100" height="16" />
            <text><![CDATA[01-2653-5]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="169" y="236" width="640" height="30" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="13"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.generateCodeline($P{printAmount}.split("\\s+")[1],"01",">","971786","+","0126535",">",$P{invoiceId})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="132" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="144" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="158" width="294" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerPostalCode}+ " " + $P{customerCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="193" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="205" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="218" width="251" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerPostalCode}+ " " + $P{customerCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="172" width="211" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{countryCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="230" width="194" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{countryCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="92" width="424" height="19" />
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.getReferenceNumber("971786",$P{invoiceId})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="172" width="186" height="16" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.getReferenceNumber("971786",$P{invoiceId})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="132" y="142" width="47" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.splitAmount($P{printAmount}.split("\\s+")[1].split("\\.")[1])]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="301" y="142" width="40" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.splitAmount($P{printAmount}.split("\\s+")[1].split("\\.")[1])]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="2" y="142" width="105" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.splitAmount($P{printAmount}.split("\\s+")[1].split("\\.")[0]).trim()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="173" y="142" width="105" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
             </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression> <![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.splitAmount($P{printAmount}.split("\\s+")[1].split("\\.")[0]).trim()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
 </summary>
 </jasperReport>
```

File `subreport.jrxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ageing-esr-40-srpski-subreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="70" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" >
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridHeight" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridWidth" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.SnapToGrid" value="false"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.Grid" value="false"/>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="customerId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDueDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="newStatusId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="printAmount" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="balance" class="java.lang.String"/>
<title>
    <band height="30">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="2" y="14" width="65" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Racun od]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="83" y="14" width="65" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Nacin pl.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="164" y="14" width="85" height="14" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Broj racuna]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="262" y="14" width="85" height="14" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Rok istekao]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="375" y="14" width="48" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Iznos]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="437" y="14" width="58" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Otvoreno]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="504" y="14" width="52" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Step.nap]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="19">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="495" y="3" width="34" height="12" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$P{newStatusId}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="356" y="3" width="67" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{printAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="262" y="3" width="100" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoiceDueDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="164" y="3" width="75" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$P{invoiceId}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="83" y="3" width="77" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Racun]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="2" y="3" width="75" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoiceDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="423" y="2" width="67" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{printAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<summary>
    <band height="20">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="266" y="0" width="163" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Ukupno CHF. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="423" y="0" width="67" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{printAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

JAVA code:

```
public static JasperPrint generateAgeingESRFile(InvoiceDTO invoice, Integer userId, Integer entityId , Integer newStatusId) throws FileNotFoundException,
        SessionInternalError {

    try {

     ContactDTOEx to=null;
     ContactDTOEx from=null;

        // This is needed for JasperRerpots to work, for some twisted XWindows issue
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
    /*
        String designFile = com.sapienter.jbilling.common.Util.getSysProp("base_dir")
                            + "designs/" + "ageing-esr-" + entityId + ".jasper";
    */

        String design = "ageing-esr-" + entityId;

    String designFile = getAgeingESRDesignFile(design, invoice);

        File compiledDesign = new File(designFile);
        LOG.debug("Generating paper esr with design file : " + designFile +  "The Ageing Step is " + newStatusId);
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(compiledDesign);
        Locale locale = (new UserBL(userId).getLocale());

    ContactBL contact = new ContactBL();
        contact.setInvoice(invoice.getId());
        to = contact.getDTO();

        entityId = invoice.getBaseUser().getEntity().getId();
        Date lastStatusChangeDate = invoice.getBaseUser().getLastStatusChange();
        contact.setEntity(entityId);
        from = contact.getDTO();

    //LOG.debug("The ageing step is " + newStatusId);
        // add all the invoice data


    HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("invoiceNumber", invoice.getPublicNumber());
        parameters.put("invoiceId", invoice.getId());
    parameters.put("newStatusId", newStatusId);
    parameters.put("totalWithTax", Util.formatMoney(invoice.getTotal(),
        invoice.getUserId(), invoice.getCurrency().getId(), false));
        parameters.put("customerId", invoice.getUserId().toString());
        parameters.put("invoiceDate", Util.formatDate(invoice.getCreateDatetime(), invoice.getUserId()));
        parameters.put("invoiceDueDate", Util.formatDate(invoice.getDueDate(), invoice.getUserId()));
        parameters.put("invoiceGeneratedDate", Util.formatDate(invoice.getCreateTimestamp(), invoice.getUserId()));
        parameters.put("statusChangeDate", Util.formatDate(lastStatusChangeDate, invoice.getUserId()));

    parameters.put("entityName", printable(from.getOrganizationName()));
        parameters.put("entityAddress", printable(from.getAddress1()));
        parameters.put("entityAddress2", printable(from.getAddress2()));
        parameters.put("entityPostalCode", printable(from.getPostalCode()));
        parameters.put("entityCity", printable(from.getCity()));
        parameters.put("entityProvince", printable(from.getStateProvince()));
        parameters.put("entityPhoneCountryCode", printable(from.getPhoneCountryCode().toString()));
    parameters.put("entityPhoneAreaCode", printable(from.getPhoneAreaCode().toString()));
    parameters.put("entityPhoneContry", printable(from.getPhoneNumber().toString()));

        parameters.put("customerOrganization", printable(to.getOrganizationName()));
        parameters.put("customerName", printable(to.getFirstName(), to.getLastName()));
        parameters.put("customerAddress", printable(to.getAddress1()));
        parameters.put("customerAddress2", printable(to.getAddress2()));
        parameters.put("customerPostalCode", printable(to.getPostalCode()));
        parameters.put("customerCity", printable(to.getCity()));
        parameters.put("customerProvince", printable(to.getStateProvince()));
        parameters.put("countryCode", printable(to.getCountryCode()));            
        parameters.put("carriedBalance", Util.formatMoney(invoice.getCarriedBalance(),
        invoice.getUserId(), invoice.getCurrency().getId(), false));

    Collection invoicePaymentMaps = invoice.getPaymentMap();
    List list = new ArrayList(invoicePaymentMaps);
    if(list==null || list.isEmpty()){
    LOG.debug("invoicePaymentMaps is null, so pass totalWithTax as param ");
    parameters.put("printAmount", Util.formatMoney(invoice.getTotal(),
            invoice.getUserId(), invoice.getCurrency().getId(), false));
    }else{
    LOG.debug("invoicePaymentMaps is not null, so pass balance as param ");
    parameters.put("printAmount", Util.formatMoney(invoice.getBalance(),
            invoice.getUserId(), invoice.getCurrency().getId(), false));
   }

        // the logo is a file
        File logo = new File(com.sapienter.jbilling.common.Util
                .getSysProp("base_dir")
                + "logos/entity-" + entityId + ".jpg");
        parameters.put("entityLogo", logo);

        BigDecimal taxTotal = new BigDecimal(0);
        int taxItemIndex = 0;
        // set report locale
        parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, locale);

        // at last, generate the report
        JasperPrint report = null;
        report = JasperFillManager.fillReport(stream, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

        stream.close();

        return report;
} catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception generating ESR receipt", e);
        return null;
    }
}  
    public JasperPrint getMultipleIdReport(List<Integer> idInvoiceList, JasperReport report) throws JRException { 
 List<JasperPrint> printList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
  for (Integer id : idInvoiceList) {
   printList.add(generateAgeingESRFile(InvoiceDTO invoice, Integer userId, Integer entityId , Integer newStatusId));
   }

  JasperPrint printFinal = null;
   for (JasperPrint jp : printList) {
  if (printFinal == null) {
    printFinal = jp;
   } else {
    List<JRPrintPage> pages = jp.getPages();
    for (JRPrintPage page : pages) {
        printFinal.addPage(page);
    }
  }
  }
 return printFinal;
  }
```

Comment: Please anyone suggest me.It is very imoportant

Comment: So your current report prints 1 invoice (invoice id), and you like to be able to print the ids you like and have one single document?

Comment: yes in the same way I need it by using list.I need to place all the invoiceIds in a list and loop them to print when I download the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You could change you report (query and structure), to take the `List<Integer>` as parameter and then generate all the invoice in same report, to generate a new page for every invoice you group on `idInvoice` and set group to page break, `<group name="idInvoice" isStartNewPage="true"></group>`.

However a pure java approach to avoid modifying the report is adding all the pages of multiple single id report to a single `JasperPrint` object

**Example**

```
//Method to add multiple single id report to single JasperPrint
public JasperPrint getMultipleIdReport(List<Integer> idInvoiceList, JasperReport report) throws JRException { 
  List<JasperPrint> printList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
  for (Integer id : idInvoiceList) {
    printList.add(getSingleIdReport(id, report));
  }

  JasperPrint printFinal = null;
  for (JasperPrint jp : printList) {
    if (printFinal == null) {
        printFinal = jp;
    } else {
        List<JRPrintPage> pages = jp.getPages();
        for (JRPrintPage page : pages) {
            printFinal.addPage(page);
        }
    }
  }
  return printFinal;
}

//Method to get a single id report, similar to your current code
public JasperPrint getSingleIdReport(int idInvoice, JasperReport report) throws JRException {
   //fill the parameter and the return the the JasperPrint for single id
   return JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, connection);
}
```

Comment: where I need to add this code in my code.Please suggest me.

Comment: You need to try to understand hit, its general code (which is better on SO), I will not give you exact code for your case, but I will be happy to explain it further if there is something you do not understand

Comment: Can't we do using hashmap.If you see my code we are using hashmap.In the same way we can't pass the parameters.

Comment: How I need to call this method getMultipleIdReport in my code.please suggest me.

Comment: Your current  generateAgeingESRFile is generating a JasperPrint (even if i do not like static and I do not know what the stream is) it is similar to the getSingleIdReport(), so you add the getMulipleIdReport and call this instead passing the list of ids (and other stuff that you need in singleIdReport)

Comment: That's the confusion how I need to add in my code this method and how o assign this as a parameter.

Comment: Please check my code i added with your code and suggest me if any changes has to do.

Comment: @Hari hmm your not really, before you had one method generating one JasperPrint, (this corresponds to my getSingleIdReport), you need to add getMultipleIdReport that always generate 1 JasperPrint but from calling the getSingleReport several time (for every idInvoice in List)

Comment: I could not understand can you please change my code.

Comment: I have edited my code but it is showing error List<JRPrintpage> cannot find symbol.Please suggest me.

Comment: For  List<JRPrint**P**age> The classes are java.util.List and net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPrintPage

Comment: can you please check my code and suggest me if there is any change

Comment: @Hari, its a bit messy for me, but you are close, pass a List of InvoiceDTO  (the invoice's you like to print) to the getMultipleIdReport, loop the InvoiceDTO and call your current generateAgeingESRFile

Comment: printList.add(generateAgeingESRFile(InvoiceDTO invoice));When I add this it is showing the error as Illegal start of expression

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562950/java-error-illegal-start-of-expression

Comment: I have seen that but i could not understand,can you please suggest me how I need to pass parameters to print InvoiceIds with generateAgeingESRFile method

Comment: I did above, pass the parameters that you need to multiple, instead of List<Integer> pass a List<InvoiceDTO>

Comment: ok how can I get printAmount and InvoiceDate and invoiceDueDate same as InvoiceIds

Comment: After passing the List<InvoiceDTO> I am getting the error as Incompatable type as this point  for (Integer id : idInvoiceList) {
    printList.add(generateAgeingESRFile(idInvoiceList));
  }

Comment: I do not want to sound harsh but it is impossibile for me to help you with all basic understanding of java, how to pass variables, how to call methods, how to loop array list ecc. I do not have complete understanding about your program, nor can I answer all these question. You need to try to understand what is happening use google ecc.

Comment: As for the comment above if you changed the parameter in metodo you need to loop on that... for (InvoiceDTO invoice : invoiceList)... but we have reached the end of this comment thread.

Comment: It is getting the same error as I used in the same way.please suggest me.