# Scala/Jasper - How to Merge Multiple PDF in Single Page

Tags: scala, jasper-reports

I have 60 PDF files I would like to show (Print) in single PDF. I have already tried googling it but it was no use for me, as all PDF append in to a single page. How do I resolve  this (I'm an new to this)

Here is my code:

```
var jasperPrint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport1, params1, new JREmptyDataSource());

var pages = jasperPrint1.getPages();
for( j <- 0 to pages.size()-1){
  var obj = pages.get(j)
  jasperPrint.addPage(obj)
}

var outDir: String = java.lang.System.getProperty("user.dir");
separator = java.io.File.separator;
outDir = outDir + separator + "public" + separator + "sample.pdf"
var baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, baos);
var outputStream = new java.io.FileOutputStream(outDir);
baos.writeTo(outputStream);
```

Comment: Can't understand you have multiple jrxml and you like to create 1 pdf, or you just like to merge 60 pdf?

Comment: I feel like to merge 60 pdf, now the all pages are append in first page @PetterFriberg

Comment: Here is some code to create 1 jasper report from multiple JasperPrint http://stackoverflow.com/a/36933630/5292302