# Combining multiple reports of the same jrxml format into a single file

Tags: spring, jasper-reports

At the moment I'm generating a pdf file using Jasper Reports in the following way.

I created a jrxml file as "singlePagePdf.jrxml"

I have declared a bean as follows

```
<bean id="singlePagePdf"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
      p:url="classpath:reports/singlePagePdf.jrxml"
      p:reportDataKey="datasource">
    <property name="headers">
        <props>
            <prop key="Content-Disposition">
                attachment; filename=singlePage.pdf
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So when the related URL is called my controller will handle it as follows.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/generate-single-pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView generatePageForEmployeePdf(@RequestParam("empId") String employeeId) {
        List<EmployeeWork> employeeWorkDetails = employeeService.getEmployeeWorkDetails(employeeId);
        JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(employeeWorkDetails);
        Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<>();
        parameterMap.put("title", "Employee Work Deails");
        parameterMap.put("employee", employeeId);
        parameterMap.put("datasource", jrDataSource);
        return new ModelAndView("invoicePdf", parameterMap);
    }
```

At the moment it successfully generates the report for a single employee. Now I want to create reports for list of employees in the same format(using the same jrxml file) and output it to a single pdf file(i.e. pdf file with multiple employee work detail records)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use another jrxml and use your current jrxml as subreport. If you are passing 1 user as parameter it will print only else it will print all users detail.

Comment: Thanks, @FahadAnjum. Currently, I'm looking for a working example asI'm having a bit difficulty in preparing that jrxml with subreports parameters.

Comment: You can do it many ways, modify report to support a query with one or multiple employes, subreport or just add the jasper print together like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/36929868/5292302

Answer (score 0):

Refer this post:
[How to collate multiple jrxml jasper reports into a one single pdf output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564163/how-to-collate-multiple-jrxml-jasper-reports-into-a-one-single-pdf-output-file/38869089#38869089)

As explained in the above post, this task can be achieved by using a loop to generate individual reports using the preferred format(singlePagePdf.jrxml) and then add them to jprintList to get the final output.