# Subroutine doesn't work

Tags: java

First time writing something here.

Why does my Subroutine not work?
I am trying to open the subroutine in the main function to get a boolean.

[image: command]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aufgabe1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int eingabe = 0; 
        int zahl = 0;
        boolean primzahl = false; 


        eingabe = scan.nextInt();//Input 1



        if (eingabe == 1) { 
            zahl = scan.nextInt(); //Input 2
            unterprogramm1(zahl);
       }

        public static boolean unterprogramm1(boolean primzahl) {
            for (int i = 0; i < zahl; i++) {
                if (zahl % i == 0) {
                    primzahl = true;
                }
            }
            return primzahl;
        }
```

Comment: You did not provide the type of `primzahl` in your method declaration.

Comment: You should be more specific. And you should learn Java first. Read a book.

Comment: i declined it in front of the code. Should i post the complete code ?

Comment: @Chris you provided the return type, but not the type of your parameter.

Comment: @Ivan maybe they are trying to learn. Don’t jump to conclusions.

Comment: @Logan even if "primzahl" has the type boolean, it causes 5 errors

Comment: @Chris is `zahl` a field? Please see how to provide a complete, minimal, and verifiable example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Logan no it is not. Where should i provide the example?

Comment: @Chris well, you can’t use a variable that hasn’t been declared. And if there is more code relevant to this question, I consider just updating it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Error: illegal start of expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562950/java-error-illegal-start-of-expression)

Comment: @Logan i do not understand your thread. New to Java :)

Comment: You can't have methods inside other methods like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `boolean primzahl` in the parameter list, instead of just `primzahl` and move the method outside of the `main` function.

Comment: Where is defined this method? In the `main` function, or outside of it?

Comment: in the 'main' funciton