# How to prevent Org Babel from wrapping Java src code blocks in boilerplate code

Tags: java, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

In Org Mode in Emacs, while writing Java src code blocks, all src code blocks get wrapped in some boilerplate code. The boilerplate code includes the default class name which is Main and a main function. The boilerplate code is not included if src code block contains a class declaration, but in all other cases it is added.

I am trying to write a public enum in src code block. When evaluating this src code block the public enum gets wrapped in the boilerplate code which then causes compilation error.

Is there a way to prevent Org Babel from automatically wrapping src code block in boilerplate code and instead use the code in src code block as it is.

BTW I am using Doom Emacs distribution of Emacs.

[image: screenshot]

I tried searching online but couldn't get a proper answer, hence I am writing this issue.

Comment: I do use eclipse for proper projects. I use org mode for making notes while learning and wanted to be able to evaluate java src code in it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [`org-babel` internals](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/f559bd1248a265662665c462b750eb5fc64dd811/lisp/org/ob-java.el#L177), we can see, that `org-babel-execute:java` calls `org-babel-java--expand-for-evaluation` function, docstring of which states:

> Expand source block for evaluation. In order to return a value we have
> to add a __toString method. In order to prevent classes without main
> methods from erroring we add a dummy main method if one is not
> provided.

So this should be an expected behavior in order to prevent errors evaluating a source block.

As for the compilation error, [Java Error: illegal start of expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24562950/1319821) seems to address it.

[The question text & screenshot doesn't look *fully* aligned to me. Not having *Java* setup currently to verify, I might miss something.]

Comment: Yes as you said this is a expected behaviour of org-babel, but I want to bypass it for certain src code blocks in the org file as it causes problem if I try to define a enum or interace as public in src blocks. the screenshot shows the error I receive when I try to execute a src block with a public enum defined in it.

Comment: I've run into this problem as well and haven't found a work-around. Adding the boilerplate code makes no sense from a programming viewpoint. For one, embedding inside another class changes the meaning of the code.  The tangled file is also named incorrectly for java standards. Even adding a main method to an arbitrary class is inappropriate, but obviously absurd with an enum. Also, org-babel-tangle isn't intended for code completion type functions, so I don't know what they were thinking. Has anyone submitted a bug report? Also, has anyone written an alternative ob-java file they can share?